# There being and there to be

Tags: meaning, there-is

Now and then I come across the constructions indicated in the heading. I'm a bit puzzled regarding their usage as a complement:

> I don't want **there to be** any more trouble. I'd like **there to be** more
>   time to think. What's the chance of **there being** an election this year?
>   What is the current thinking about **there being** more than one Universe?

Are they entirely interchangeable or is there some difference in the meaning? Apparently, it ought to be because sometimes it seems that one fits the context better than the other. For example:

> So your experiences, which represent **there to be** an external world of
>   physical objects (including your body), give rise to systematically
>   mistaken beliefs about your world (such as that you are now sitting at
>   a computer).

If I were the one who wrote this sentence, I would definitely have used **there being**, but the real author chose the other variant. So, what is the difference (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

The
 difference
 is
 entirely
 in
 the requirements
 of
 the
 matrix
 clause.
 "Want"
 and
 "like"
 take
 an
 infinitive
 clause,
 while
 "The
 chances
 of"
 and
 "thinking
 about"
 take
 gerunds.
 There
 is
 no
 discernable
 explanation
 for
 these
 preferences:
 they're
 simply
 arbitrary
 facts
 about
 present
 day
 English.

Comment: Hmm...What's wrong with these sentences?
_I like there being a special charm about this place. The chances of there to be a gun on him are fairly high._

Comment: What's wrong is that they are not idiomatic English.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Would they be if put as "_there to be a special charm_" and "_there being a gun_" respectively?

Comment: @MvLog: No; the to-infinitive is mainly used in the expression "would like X to be Y", which implies that X is not currently Y. You could use a subordinate clause: "I like that there is a special charm about this place." However, it might sound best to rephrase to use a noun ("I like the special charm about this place") or to split the sentence in two ("I like this place. It has a special charm.").